# How can I create reusable test code without creating circular dependencies?

Tags: java, maven, hamcrest, clover

Consider two projects.

- mycompany-foo
- mycompany-foo-tests

In mycompany-foo, I define some objects that I want to use in many other projects. In order to facilitate code reuse, mycompany-foo-tests defines hamcrest matchers that can match mycompany-foo objects.

The problem is that mycompany-foo-tests would depend on mycompany-foo in order for me to create a matcher for it. And then mycompany-foo would depend on mycompany-foo-tests so that I can do some matching within mycompany-foo's tests. This creates a circular dependency. Something I want to avoid.

I solved this problem by simply adding the matchers to mycompany-foo, removing the "tests" project, and exporting a test jar that contains the matchers as a "test-jar".

Everything was going smoothly until I learned that Atlassian's clover installed artifacts that it creates into my m2 repo[1]. This overrides my test-jar and causes downstream projects to fail when it can't initialize the clover version of my matchers.

The advice I see is to not create a test-jar, but rather go back to what I was doing before. That is, having a whole separate project for matchers. Is there a way to do that without creating a circular dependency?

[1] https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CLOV-331

Comment: If `foo-tests` is a "library" then it should NOT depend on `foo`. Simple as that. If it needs to, then there's no point in making a library.

Comment: Why should mycompany-foo depend on mycompany-foo-tests?

Comment: @LouisWasserman I guess that `mycompany-foo-tests` contains test-utils which are needed in `mycompany-foo` to write actual tests.

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak, that's exactly correct. That is why today they live in the same project and I simply have maven create a test-jar as a secondary artifact. Unfortunately, the clove bug I linked to describes a behavior in which it override the test-jar with its own. That is the motivation to possibly separate the projects. I clearly would prefer not to do this.

Comment: Firstly, it sounds like you have a problem with clover and your build pipe line, not with circular dependencies. Maybe it's worth not using clover at all? Secondly, I cannot see why you need to generate test jar. Lastly, I really recommend using shazamcrest - very simple and powerful tool, you will not have to write any custom matchers at all ;)

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak, You're right. The problem is with clover. Unfortunately, I need to use it.

Comment: Whoever voted -1, could you possibly undo your downvote? I'm assuming it was downvoted because I floated the idea of doing something that wasn't a best practice (ie invoking Cunningham's law to get the right answer). Clearly if I had the "right" answer I wouldn't have had to ask what the "right" answer is. By downvoting, you simply hide a potential discussion on what the better practice is from people who are also going down the wrong path. If there's a real problem with the question (lack of research, etc...) by all means, let me know what I can do to improve the question.

Comment: I'd consider custom matchers on foo objects to be production code and not separate it out into a project/JAR. Write tests for those matchers as well. Any other project that needs the matchers also needs the foo objects, so keep them together.

Comment: @DavidHarkness I understand why you feel that way, but I partially disagree. I think it should stay together in the same project, but I think it's fine to deliver a separate test-jar as a secondary artifact. I don't want to deliver test code, but I do want to provide additional tools to people who want to write unit tests that involve those objects.

Comment: I'm going to leave this as a comment rather than an answer since this is the solution to my real problem and not the one I asked about. One can get around Clover overriding test-jars in the local repo with instrumented jars by changing the goal to be instrument-test rather than instrument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Don't separate production code and its tests/test-utils into separate projects.
2. Don't write matchers for your objects, there are tools that will do this for you (e.g. [shazamcrest](https://github.com/shazam/shazamcrest)).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the library. I'll research it to see if it fits my needs.